# Switching between places and tree sidebar modes quits Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, mount, gnome

I have the following issue in my system (11.10 - GNOME3). When switching between places and tree sidebar modes Nautilus quits suddenly. When I open it again the mode I selected is active.

I realize that's a minor bug, but I use this a lot it would be great if someone can provide me a workaround.

The described behavior does not happen always... sometimes it just works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related with a nautilus extension: http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/

I totally forgot that I posted this here. I just uninstalled the thing and all worked again smoothly. However I enjoyed the extension and try it again check if it's fixed.